# How to display both HTML and Plain Text in RichTextbox or WebBrowser Control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have database column that can either contain plain text or HTML. I want to display it in a WPF window in either RichTextBox or WebBrowser control. Right now if I use the WebBrowser control , the HTML displays fine. But the Text gets all messed up. The formatting is gone. For example:

If the Actual Text is:

> This is a Test
>   This is another Test

It gets displayed as :

> This is a TestThis is another Test.

Here's the XAML Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="DataListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
 <ListView.View>
    <GridView >
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"></GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Memo" Width="Auto"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Memo}"></GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
<WebBrowser Name="DataBrowser" resources:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding ElementName=DataListView,Path=SelectedItem.Memo}" Height="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
<WebBrowser.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
        <SkewTransform/>
        <RotateTransform/>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
</WebBrowser.RenderTransform>
</WebBrowser>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
foreach(var item in dataList)
{
    DataItems.Add(new DataClass
    {
        Name = item.Name,
        Memo = item.Memo
    });
}

public class DataClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Memo {get;set;}
}
```

Any idea how can I get this fixed?

Comment: are you saving the actual rich text into the database?

Comment: @nalnpir: No. It may just come in as plain text.

Comment: Then thats your problem, if you want it formatted, you need to save the formatted text, not the plain one

Comment: @nalnpir: Well, I may be wrong, when I copy the text from the database column into the notepad, the formatting stays.

Comment: do you do the same with the RichTextControl? it seems like in one case your text looks like "This is a Test\nThis is another Test." and on the other one "This is a TestThis is another Test." like you re missing the \n

Comment: It's the same with both controls. The text is the same and formatted with \n. It only goes missing when viewing it in the controls

Comment: can you put the code you are using to do this? it sounds weird

Comment: Added the code.